# .NET Framework C# Console App doesn't recognise OR-Tools directive

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, google-maps, or-tools

I have a problem with OR-Tools. I'm using VS 2019 and I want use OR-Tools (with GMap if it's possible on Windows Forms App .NET Framework in the near future).
I downloaded it from Manage NuGet Packages and when I pasted code from this link:
[https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/dotnet#complete-program](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

**I've got 7 errors:**
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHXjV.png)

I also downloaded Google.Protobufs because I think it was required, but nothing changed:
[Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlPvq.png)

I don't know how to use Google OR-Tools on C#, I use this for the first time. I hope that there is a way to use it with GMap, because I want combine these two elements (OR-Tools and GMaps) to click points on the map and make a route based on travelling salesman problem.

Comment: instead of `make run ...`, try `dotnet run <program>.csproj `. See github.com/google/or-tools/issues/3558 for more context.

Comment: Ok, I tried something different. I created project which uses Target Framework .NET Core 3.1 and surprisingly this code worked, but on project with .NET Framework 4.7.2 it doesn't working. Is there a way to add netcore 3.1 to project with net framework 4.7.2?

Comment: Or net6.0 with net framework 4.7.2? Or combine with older versions?

Comment: https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/3503

Answer (score -2):

`using Google.OrTools.LinearSolver;` is the key.

Comment: So should I write for get access to this key or something like that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive

Comment: Hmm... I don't quite understand. Is there a different type of directive which I must use?

Comment: Show please the whole code of your module.